# App showcase scrolling script

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll

I'm about to create a scroll function like happn.com. I want the device and background to freeze and some different text sections to scroll. The app screenshots inside the device should change as well. I have tried the ScrollMagic tutorial but I cant figure out how to use it with the already existing elements.

I have been struggling with this the whole week. Does anyone know any framework or tutorials I can use for this?

Thanks!

Examples:
https://www.happn.com/
https://www.uber.com/sv-SE/

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you can do it via **parallax effect**.

Check this link: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't actually see how to do this with the parallax effect. I mean it's actually a image inside a div I want to change based on scroll. But I might be wrong. 

Please explain how you mean a bit further.

Comment: @Erfra It was just the simple usage. Check more examples, like this one: http://gardenestudio.com.br/index.php. The basic idea is in manipulations of elements depending on scroll. I didn't use it yet, but as i know, you can do this via parallax.